# Notepad++ syntax highlight - php keywords in different cases

Tags: php, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

In Notepad++ PHP syntax highlight works only for keywords in lower case (preg_replace, define, etc) and doesn't work for different cases (getSingleton, getTableName, etc). How to change it?

```
Settings -> Preferences -> Highlighting -> Match case
```

doesn't change anything.

Comment: Is this any use to you  https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/f58b6b26/

Comment: I add my keywords (getSingleton, getTableName, etc) to Settings -> Styles configuration -> php -> WORD -> User keywords but it doesn't work.

Comment: this works for me: Settings ->Styles , choose php -> add user defined words in lower case

Comment: SOLUTION: Keywords must be add in lower case and now it's work :)

Comment: Thanks everybody for help :)